# Having white spaces in your Windows username fails the "create" command - Yarn

Tags: javascript, cmd, terminal, yarnpkg

I'm trying to create a new next js app with the help of yarn but it throws an error saying that there is no command with the name of `'C:\Users\Sharma'`

My user name is "Sharma Ji" So there might be some issue with the space in the name.. I'm not sure how to rectify it.

[image]

Comment: [See if any of these solutions work](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6630). Apparently it's [still an on-going issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6851).

Comment: Thanks, @Andy One of the solutions worked. It seems that the issue is opened for a long time and no body fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue has been going on for a long time. It was created approx 4 years ago

Here's a workaround that can be used instead.

```
yarn config set cache-folder c:\root\yarn\cache
yarn config set prefix c:\root\yarn\packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a space in my username. This worked for me.

Step 1: Create an environment folder for your project or all projects.

Step 2: Open the terminal within the environment folder location.

Step 3: Run `yarn config set prefix .yarn`

Step 4: Run `yarn create next-app` or `yarn create vite`, etc.

In this method, you won't be able to install packages globally. That's why I'm suggesting you use a folder to contain all the projects instead.

[image]